# Trouble in understanding problem statement.

Tags: calculus

**Problem:** Explain the remark made by Galileo

> neither is the number of squares less than the totality of all numbers nor the latter greater than the former.

If the number of squares is $n$ then as far as I understand 
$$x^2_1+x^2_2+...+x^2_n>n \text{ and } x^2_1+x^2_2+...+x^2_n<n$$

But this does not make any sense. Please explain where am I going wrong. FYI this is an exercise problem in a Calculus Textbook.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_paradox

Answer (score 2):

The remark is about the set of *all* squares vs. the set of *all* natural numbers.

It's a cryptic way of saying they are equal in [cardinality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality).

Comment: ... except that the concept of cardinality had not yet been formulated.  This was a step along the way to that.